# A (predicate) logical expression and its meaning

Tags: logic

I will use an example sentence from Russell, so if we let **W** represent the predicate “... authored *Waverley* “, then:

**(x)(Wx → (y)(Wy → y=x))**

would express the same thing as the sentence "At most one person authored *Waverley*".

Now if one would introduce **(z)** would it matter? If one put in the following expression:

**(z)(Wz → z=x)**

would it change the meaning, or would it ***only*** be redundant? Would the following:

**(x)(Wx → (y)(z)(Wy → y=x )∧(Wz → z=x))**

then be the same as

**(x)(Wx → (y)(Wy → y=x))** ?

Comment: There is a *connective* (like "and") inside : **(Wy → y=x )(Wz → z=x) ??? If not, the formula is "ill-formed" i.e. not correct according to the syntactical rules of the language.

Comment: Thanks, so if I add '∧' to (Wy → y=x )(Wz → z=x) like this: (Wy → y=x )∧(Wz → z=x) it would be _syntactically_ correct? @Mauro ALLEGRANZA

Comment: Yes, now it is... and we can say that it is superfluous. "P and P" is equivalent to "P"; thus **(y)(z)[(Wy → y=x )∧(Wz → z=x)]** add nothing to **(z)(Wz → z=x)**

Comment: Thanks,@MauroALLEGRANZA as I suspected. So if one would have substituted the 'z' with a 'y', the identity (if one can use that word here) would have been easier to recognise, because one would simply have used the expression **(y)(Wy → y=x)** twice? However 'z' and 'y' as signs are obviously different, but that don't matter at all? Am I correct? So z = y in this case?

Comment: In a quantified expression like **(z)(Wz → z=x)** the *bound* variable **z** in not meaningful, i.e. we can change it with any other (like **y**) without affecting the meaning, **provided that** we do not use a variable already present in the formula and free (like **x** in the example), because in this case we have problems.

Answer (score 1):

The z would be completely redundant. This is because 'what you're doing with z', i.e. (Wz → z=x), is the same as what you're doing with y, and they are both from the same set; that is, every z could've been y and vice versa. This together means every case of z is already caught by y.

---

#### Longer explanation:

There is a very intuitive mathematical rule that says that we can change the name of [*bound variables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) (variables can be bound by existential or universal quantification). Basically, it means that the following two are equivalent:

- (x)(P(x))
- (y)(P(y))

'x' or 'y' are just names, and they don't carry meaning.

There is another rule that says we can swap universal quantifications as we like, such that the following two are equivalent:

- (x)(y)(P(x) ∧ Q(y))
- (y)(x)(P(x) ∧ Q(y))

Note that this is not the same rule as above, i.e. we didn't rename x to y and vice versa, because the inner experssion "P(x) ∧ Q(y)" doesn't change. Only the order of the quantifications is changed.

Intuitively, these two together show that we may rename the z you added to y, yielding:

(x)(Wx → (y)(y)(Wy → y=x) ∧ (Wy → y=x))

<sub>Note: this is no good notation, because the y's are ambiguous. This is just to give you the idea of the intuitive notion.</sub>

On both sides of the ∧ we have the same expression, so we can simplify it:

(x)(Wx → (y)(y)(Wy → y=x))

And then we can also remove one of the y's...

(x)(Wx → (y)(Wy → y=x))

Bringing us back to the initial expression.